# Is it a bug to represent complex projection use spring data Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My aggregation like that

```js
db.data.aggregate(
{
    "$project" : {
        "hour" : {"$hour" : "$time"},
        "_id" : 0,
        "time" : 1,
        "rawValue" : 1,
        "fid" : 1
    }
},
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {"hour":"$hour","fid" : "$fid"},
        "maxTime" : {
            "$max" : "$time"
        },
        "minTime" : {
            "$min" : "$time"
        },
        "maxVal" : {
            "$max" : "$rawValue"
        },
        "minVal" : {
            "$min" : "$rawValue"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project" : {
        "hour" : "$_id.hour",
        "_id" : 0,
        "value" : {
            "$divide" : [
                {"$subtract":["$maxVal","$minVal"]},
                {"$divide" : [{"$subtract" : ["$maxTime","$minTime"]},60 * 60 * 1000]}
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$hour",
        "avgH" : {
            "$sum" : "$value"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort" : {"_id" : 1}
}
)
```

This is the input document:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("538408349aedda51a98a37f8"),
    "_class" : "ruijian.common.baseInfo.domain.FunctionValuePO",
    "fid" : "320102A002_01_0400_040000",
    "buildingid" : "320102A002",
    "time" : ISODate("2012-12-31T17:31:36Z"),
    "coding" : "01000",
    "rawValue" : 1691.2
}
```

my java code

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(criteria),
        project("time","rawValue","fid").andExclude("_id")
                            .and("time").project("hour").as("hour"),
        group("hour","fid").max("time").as("maxTime")
                            .min("time").as("minTime")
                            .max("rawValue").as("maxVal")
                            .min("rawValue").as("minVal"),
        project().and("_id.hour").as("hour")
                            .andExpression("(maxVal - minVal) / ((maxTime - minTime) / (60 * 60 * 1000))").as("value")
                            .andExclude("_id"),
        group("hour").sum("value").as("avgH"),
        sort(Direction.ASC,"_id")
    );
```

**it was the 'andExpression("(maxVal - minVal) / ((maxTime - minTime) / (60 * 60 * 1000))")' that convert to mongodb expression is "$divide": [
                    {
                        "$subtract": [
                            "$maxVal",
                            "$minVal"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "$subtract": [
                            "$maxTime",
                            "$minTime"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "$multiply": [
                            60,
                            60,
                            1000
                        ]
                    }
                ]**

the exception info is *[Command execution failed:  Error [exception: Expression $divide takes exactly 2 arguments. 3 were passed in.]*

Comment: Could help a bit to show what you have done so far. I presume you want to aggregate to a class output using the mongoOperations form of aggregate rather than raw methods.

Comment: i have reedit my question,please help